# Insert Record according to foreign key in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

I want To Insert Record According To Foreign Key(project_id) But Can't Inserted.I don't Know what's the problem

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
//    protected $fillable = ['project_id'];
    protected $guarded = [];


    public function task(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Project;
use App\Models\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TaskController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index(){
        return view('task');
    }


    public function insert(Request $request)
    {
        $validation = $request->validate([
            'title'=>'required',
        ]);




        Task::create($validation);
        return redirect()->back()->with('success','data inserted');
    }
}
```

Please Guide me How to Insert Record According To Foreign Key(project_id)

Comment: I cannot see anywhere in your code that applies some value to `project_id` field!

Comment: Whats coming in `$request`? show us dump

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are not using fillable you must put all the fields 1 by 1 into that table.

Example:

```
$task = new Task();
$task->title = 'title';
$task->save();
```

If you want to use `Task::create([]);` you must declare them into fillable properties all the fields you want to insert in the table.

You could do:

```
$request->validate([
            'title'=>'required',
        ]);

    Task::create($request->validated());
```

Don't forget to add the columns in fillable array

Comment: General error: 1364 Field 'project_id' doesn't have a default value

Comment: it given me this error

Comment: Exactly, because you havent added it and its going null on the database

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the foreign key value, unless it's null-able.
And as Apollo said, you need to add the column in the fillable array in your model

Answer (score 0):

Rename relation name,

In Task

```
  public function project(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
```

In Peojct

```
 public function task(){
        return $this->yourRelation(Project::class); yourRelation -> //hasOne , hasMany
    }
```

Now when creating task use this code . $project => existed Project Model instance , $project  = Project::find(1) // Project::find($request->project_id)

```
$project->task()->create($request->validated());
```

When directly creating task you need project_id and it should be fillable in Project Model.

Answer (score 0):

#model

you must use this array in the model, and the pivot table's name must be incorrect.

```
protected $fillable = [
        'title'
    ];
```

##controller

```
    public function insert(Request $request)
    {
        $validation = $request->validate([
            'title'=>'required',
        ]);
        $task=Task::create($request->toArray());
        $task->projects()->sync([project key]);
       }
```